# Swift Sequence Iterator that hides some of the underlying values in an Array

Tags: swift, iterator, sequence

I'm just trying to create a simple Sequence that hides some of the underlying values stored in an Array. I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I have a private `Box` which has a `String` and some metadata. When I iterate over the `NameList` I just want to get back the `String`.

```
// A box to store private metadata with the element

fileprivate class Box {
    var name: String
    fileprivate var privateMetadata: Int

    fileprivate init(name: String, metadata: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.privateMetadata = metadata
    }
}

// The public API to retrieve the list of elements
// I want to be able to iterate over NameList and get back only the `name` property.
// The private metadata should be hidden.

public class NameList: Sequence {

     private var contents = [Box]()

     func add(_ name: String) {
         let metaData = ... // some function to generate private data
         self.contents.append(Box(name: name, metadata: metaData))
     }

     // just want to get back the name property
     func makeIterator() -> ??? {
         ???
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is a type-erased iterator based on the
(lazy) map of the contents to its "name" property:

```
public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<String> {
    return AnyIterator(contents.lazy.map { $0.name }.makeIterator())
}
```

And just for fun: If you define a `map` on iterators
which returns an new iterator iterating over the transformed elements

```
extension IteratorProtocol {
    func map<V>(_ transform: @escaping (Element) -> V) -> AnyIterator<V> {
        var iter = self
        return AnyIterator { return iter.next().map(transform) }
    }
}
```

then you can implement the `NameList.makeIterator()` method as

```
public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<String> {
    return contents.makeIterator().map { $0.name }
}
```